# need to translate jquery code into ruby/rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my Rails app, the images only show when the code is on my home page (the one which has root to:, in my routes.rb)

```
<div id = "carousel">
    <img id ="rotate_images" src="assets/1.1.png"/>

    <div id = "back">
    <img src = "assets/arrow_back.png">
  </div>  

    <div id = "forward">
    <img src = "assets/arrow_forward.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use the code above on other pages in my app I get an error 404 - file not found. it can't find the right location of the assets folder. However, when I use rails code to link to the images, it works everywhere in my app:

```
<div id = "carousel">
    <%= image_tag "1.1.png", :id => "rotate_images" %>

    <div id = "back">
      <%= image_tag "arrow_back.png" %>
  </div>  

    <div id = "forward">
      <%= image_tag "arrow_forward.png" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

So I think it's best I change my jquery image slider to ruby/rails code. Pity, because I spent a lot of time making it. Could someone translate the jquery code below to ruby/rails or put me on the right track as to how to do it? Thanks for any help.

```
<script>

$('#back').on({
      'click': function () {
          var origsrc = $(rotate_images).attr('src');
          var src = '';
          if (origsrc == 'assets/3.1.png') src = 'assets/2.1.png';
          if (origsrc == 'assets/2.1.png') src = 'assets/1.1.png';
          if (origsrc == 'assets/1.1.png') src = 'assets/1.1.png';
          $(rotate_images).attr('src', src);
      }
});

$('#forward').on({
      'click': function () {
          var origsrc = $(rotate_images).attr('src');
          var src = '';
          if (origsrc == 'assets/1.1.png') src = 'assets/2.1.png';
          if (origsrc == 'assets/2.1.png') src = 'assets/3.1.png';
          if (origsrc == 'assets/3.1.png') src = 'assets/3.1.png';
          $(rotate_images).attr('src', src);
      }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the asset pipeline.

```
 if (origsrc == '<%= asset_path('1.1.pg') %>') src = '<%= asset_path('2.1.png') %>';
```

You can use this ruby injection on all the `src =` lines.

Comment: Thanks for that.not at host computer but will be later today and check it out.don't see why people down voted my question.